# Are amoled High Resolution displays compatible with arduino?

Tags: lcd, high-resolution, arduino

I was wondering if I can hook up a high resolution amoled display such as this [one](https://www.alibaba.com/product-detail/AUO-1-4-inch-round-lcd_60506811833.html) to an arduino microcontroller?

Answer (score 0):

It use standard [MIPI](http://mipi.org/specifications/display-interface) interface. I doubt it can be driven directly by arduino. Take a look at this [project](https://hackaday.io/project/364-mipi-dsi-display-shieldhdmi-adapter), it based on FPGA controller Xilinx Spartan-6. AFAIK it is the only one that can make a bridge between arduino and MIPI DSI displays.

I think that I2C or SPI OLED displays are more easy to implement natively on arduino. Look for 128X64 OLED 0.96" I2C IIC SPI Serial LED Display Module or similar if it fit to your project.

Comment: Note that most if not all I²C and SPI OLED screens are not only incapable of video (due to bus bandwidth), but they also flicker badly, so for some applications they may be unacceptable.

Comment: @Ruslan Yeas, video over slow serial channels will produce some artifacts, but for informational purpose, like display IP, CPU load and so on, it more than enough without bothering eyes